# Cannot find symbol method "getSupportFragmentManager()"

Tags: android

This method `getSupportFragmentManager()` belongs to `FragmentActivity`, 
how can I replace this method, if I used only `extends Fragment`?

I get this error

> Error:(30, 42) error: cannot find symbol method getSupportFragmentManager()

using this code in `public class MapsFragment extends FragmentActivity`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps,container, false);   
  if (mMap == null) {
    // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
    if (mMap != null) {
      mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(57.70, 11.96)).title("Marker"));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

instead of

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the fragment manager from a Fragment, even from the support library, you should use the *getFragmentManager()* method.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()